# Nullpointer Exception on launching JNLP file (load netbeans 6.5 modules) with jdk 7 u 25 and higher versions

Tags: java, java-7, jnlp, netbeans-platform

### Application Details:

Application based on Netbeans Platform 6.5
JDK 7 u 25 or any higher version.
JNLP

### NOTE:

This issue is not coming with jdk 7 u 21. But all versions higher than u21 have this issue.

### User Action:

User enters the url of jnlp file in any browser, say chrome, to download the jnlp file in local system. After JNLP file is downloaded, user clicks on it to launch application.

### Behaviour:

When jnlp file is clicked, splash screen opens and netbeans platform based modules start downloading. Once download is complete, these modules are loaded. A Nullpointer Exception is observed while loading modules.

### Exception:

```
FINE [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: getOrder for [MultiFileObject@9e9ee3c[Toolbars/Explorers], MultiFileObject@1b1a7ef6[Toolbars/File]]
WARNING [org.openide.loaders.FolderList]: cannot compute data objects for MultiFileObject@172d3d[Toolbars]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEvent(Mutex.java:1334)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:345)
    at org.openide.awt.AWTTask.<init>(AWTTask.java:52)
    at org.openide.awt.ToolbarPool$Folder.postCreationTask(ToolbarPool.java:585)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance.processObjects(FolderInstance.java:653)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderInstance$Listener.finished(FolderInstance.java:934)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.createBoth(FolderList.java:873)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.getObjects(FolderList.java:562)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList.access$300(FolderList.java:74)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask.computeResult(FolderList.java:955)
[catch] at org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask.run(FolderList.java:933)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
SEVERE [org.openide.util.RequestProcessor]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.NotifyExcPanel.notify(NotifyExcPanel.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager.publish(NbErrorManager.java:85)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging$LookupDel.publish(TopLogging.java:798)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.loaders.FolderList$ListTask.run(FolderList.java:938)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Exception in thread "Folder recognizer" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImplPP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.SunToolkit.getSystemEventQueueImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.core.NotifyExcPanel.notify(NotifyExcPanel.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.core.NbErrorManager.publish(NbErrorManager.java:85)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging$LookupDel.publish(TopLogging.java:798)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.doNotify(RequestProcessor.java:1072)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1016)**
```

Comment: Not an answer as to why it happens, but I had a similar problem with one of my webstart apps that broke with 7u25.  It seemed to be related to [this bug](https://community.oracle.com/message/11081291#11081291) with the AWT event handling thread getting the wrong context classloader, and could be worked around by enabling the Java console in the control panel.

Comment: I tried after enabling java console but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: In jconsole, I found an Inactive RequestProcessor thread: Name: Inactive RequestProcessor thread [Was:Logging Flush/org.netbeans.core.startup.TopLogging$NonClose]
State: TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.Object@a80bf6d
Total blocked: 45  Total waited: 45

Stack trace: 
java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:950)